# How to end user delete permission after authorizing for Forge Autodesk app

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have created an app in Forge autodesk, Then I using authorize (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/) to end user authorizing for my app. How to end user remove authorize in my app

Answer (score 0):

The authorization the user gave to your application is not really persisted by Autodesk, so there is no need to explicitly remove it.

What does happen, however, is that your user's Autodesk credentials are remembered in cookies, and if you want to allow your users to clear these, I would suggest looking at the following blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/log-out-forge.